What tool to convert an OTB (bitmap font) to a TTF or OTF font?
I have this wonderful old MiscFree font on linux that I was able to convert to OTB. Unfortunately, now, I have to use mac at work, and it does not support OTB fonts...
How could I convert it to TTF or OTF formats ?
Here is the font : https://github.com/hl037/MiscFixed13-12

Your OTB font is an (unofficial) extension of the OpenType bitmap format, not supported in non-Linux environments.
The free (both libre and gratis) FontForge does this and purports to be available for both Linux and MacOS X.
There's also Vertopal's on-line converter to generate TTF.
Converting bitmap fonts to vector formats generally has ... underwhelming results. The problem is that bitmap fonts don't normally contain hinting or kerning information to optimize the appearance of a font at anything other than the "default" size. If your OTB font is effectively a 12-point font, the TTF/OTF version isn't going to look good at 8 points or at 16 points or at any size other than 12 points.
I thus don't recommend this course. It would be better to try to match this font with a known font using (for example) a site like IdentiFont and then get the font so identified already in vector TTF/OTF format.

Actually, it's only for terminal use (programming) always in a monospace context, so no kerning nor hinting nedeed except for the defaults that make it to be displayed. I will also specifically use it at 12pt or multiples. I already modded the font so I won't be able to find it on identiFont :/

I tried with fontforge, but it always tries to "smooth" it while I would like to keep the exact pixels...

Vertopal's online converter failed to convert it

Even in a terminal, TTFs are still vector fonts and smoothing is A Thing. However, some research indicates that the Linux terminal - at least in some distros - can support OTB fonts directly - see, for example, this Ask Ubuntu question. You didn't specify which version of which distro you're using, so it may or may not be useful to you.

On linux, the font work great as OTB. But I need it on mac

I added a link to the font in the question

Try opening it in FontForge and saving it as a DFONT file, which is a legacy Mac format that's a TTF with the bitmap data in the data fork. That's sorta my last best stab at it; I'm not really a Mac or Linux guy, so I'm just digging with Google and trying to analyse the results.

After a combo of writing a fontforge python script, and using fontbird, I was able to get a ttf working on mac... but it's messy :/
